# Are there any different Twitter pixel events than PageView?

Tags: events, twitter, event-tracking

The default Twitter pixel script contains this code

```js
twq('track','PageView');
```

to trigger a PageView event (conversion).

In the [documentation](https://business.twitter.com/en/help/campaign-measurement-and-analytics/conversion-tracking-for-websites.html) it states:

> Choose the type of conversion you’d like to track with this tag. Your Twitter Ads dashboard reports on conversions by conversion type.
>   Here are the types:
>
> **Site visit**: User visits your site
>
> **Purchase**: User completes a purchase of a product or service on your
>   site
>
> **Download**: User downloads a file, such as a white paper or software
>   package, from your site
>
> **Sign up**: User signs up for your service, newsletter, or email
>   communication
>
> **Custom**: This is a catch-all category for a custom action that does not
>   fall into one of the categories above

Does this mean that I can trigger these conversion types by the `twq('track', event)` function? If so, what is the syntax?

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Comment: No not yet. The developers should read this question.

Comment: I don't think that will happen. The documentation lacking compared to other "pixels", but in the end I implemented custom events using Google Tag Manager since I already had that set up.

Answer (score 3):

It appears they've expanded their documentation slightly in this regard, but it's still vague:

> A conversion event can be any "Action" that a user completes on your site which you would like to track. It does not have to be a purchase, but can also be a shopping cart update, a newsletter sign up, etc. Choose the type of conversion you’d like to track with this tag. Available tag types are Site Visit, Purchase, Sign Up, Download, or Custom.  Choose “Custom” if you’re tracking an action other than the conversion events we’ve predefined.

There is, however, an example of this in the documentation:

Under the question [How to setup advanced conversion tracking to monitor campaign ROI?](https://business.twitter.com/en/help/campaign-measurement-and-analytics/conversion-tracking-for-websites.html) there's this:

[image]

You'll notice the `Purchase` event, above. Unfortunately it doesn't give up the syntax for the two word events like Sign up. Sigh.

There is also [this post on their developer forums](https://twittercommunity.com/t/need-to-know-how-to-fire-custom-pixels-and-signup-pixels-using-universal-website-tag/99942/2?u=secretdev) from an employee (date Jan 2018) indicating they are moving away from the other custom event types:

> Due to a roadmap change, we are actively supporting “PageView” and “Purchase” tag types. But this does not mean that you can’t still track sign ups or custom events.

In their documentation there is also this disclaimer:

> The purchase tag must executed independently of 'PageView' tag type, otherwise the dynamic values will be overwritten.

This appears to suggest these additional event types must be **in replacement of** the `PageView` event, but again it's unclear. If you tell Twitter to create a `Purchase` conversion event, the snippet it provides still uses `PageView`. It's very confusing.

**Update:** From my tests it appears the above code (with `Purchase` event) fires, and is tracked correctly, by Twitter.

Comment: Three and half years later and I'm still no clearer on this